# Specify download folder in RSelenium does not work

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

Because my  [previous question](http://www.example.com/) remained unsolved, I tried to specify the download directory using firefox instead of chrome.

So I specified the download directory:

```
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting=FALSE,
                             browser.download.dir = "~/",
                             browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk="text/csv",
                             browser.download.folderList = 2L))

remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities=fprof)
```

as exactly is done [here](http://cattleguard.roughdraft.io/40699d08b524a0eaac71-reproducible-research-with-rselenium).

However, the files still get downloaded in my default download directory, rather than my working directory in R.

Does anyone have a clue what I might be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try specifying the folder exactly in the place of `"~/"`

Comment: Yes. Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: I have the same problem here. If you go to about:config, you will see that browser.download.dir is missing

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65201209/12135618

Answer (score 5):

This looks to be caused by the bug [here](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/200).  As a work around until it is fixed you could simply double escape everything, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Rselenium)

file_path <- getwd() %>% str_replace_all("/", "\\\\\\\\")
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = file_path,
                                 browser.download.folderList = 2L,
                                 browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile = "text/csv",
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "text/csv")
                            )
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for hours!  Many thanks!

Comment: For me the strategy of replacing / by \\\\\\\\ did not work on Macintosh, I do not know if the bug has already been fixed as of July 2022. I simply specified `file_path <- getwd()`, the same `fprof`, and then set the driver as `rD<- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"), extraCapabilities = fprof)`